# while adding an asset to hyperledger got error that particular field is missing

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

i made a business network using hyperledger composer playground i want add an asset in the registry but while adding it is saying that t: Instance com.acn.hps.aops.ims.EvidenceDoc#4439 missing required field owner

```
.cto file
asset EvidenceDoc identified by evidenceId{
  o String evidenceId
  o Owner owner
  }
participant Owner identified by AuthorityId{
  o String AuthorityId

   }
transaction addasset{
o EvidenceDoc evidenceDocJson
 }

.qry file
.qry file

enter code here
query getOwnerbyId{ 
      description: "Get owner of the evidence asset by its ID" 
      statement: 
      SELECT com.acn.hps.aops.ims.Superuser
      WHERE (AuthorityId == _$AuthorityId)

             } 
logic.js file

/**
* @param {com.acn.hps.aops.ims.AddEvidence} addAsset
* @transaction
*/
function AddingEvidence(addAsset){

    return getAssetRegistry('com.acn.hps.aops.ims.EvidenceDoc')
 .then(function (AssetRegistry) {
 // Get the factory for creating new asset instances.
 var factory = getFactory();
  var result = query('getOwnerbyId',

 {AuthorityId:'1'/*addAsset.evidenceDocJson.owner.AuthorityId*/});

// Create the Evidence.
  var evidence = factory.newResource('com.acn.hps.aops.ims', 'EvidenceDoc', 
  addAsset.evidenceDocJson.evidenceId);

     evidence.owner = result[0]

 // Add the asset to the asset registry.
  return AssetRegistry.add(evidence);
   })

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the query is needed here. Try this.

```
.cto

namespace com.acn.hps.aops.ims
asset EvidenceDoc identified by evidenceId{
  o String evidenceId
  o Owner owner
  }
participant Owner identified by AuthorityId{
  o String AuthorityId
   }
transaction addasset{
o EvidenceDoc evidenceDocJson
 }

script.js

/**
* @param {com.acn.hps.aops.ims.addasset} addAsset
* @transaction
*/
function AddingEvidence(addAsset){

    return getAssetRegistry('com.acn.hps.aops.ims.EvidenceDoc')
 .then(function (AssetRegistry) {
 // Get the factory for creating new asset instances.
 var factory = getFactory();
// Create the Evidence.
  var evidence = factory.newResource('com.acn.hps.aops.ims', 'EvidenceDoc', 
  addAsset.evidenceDocJson.evidenceId);

     evidence.owner = addAsset.evidenceDocJson.owner

 // Add the asset to the asset registry.
  return AssetRegistry.add(evidence);
   })

   }
```

Comment: @Sneha...Thanks for your answer...I have tried this...In this we are specifying the owner by own but whose ever is creating the asset is the owner. thats why i am trying to get the owner while the owner is creating an asset...also i need to provide value to the owner participants field and there are many fields in the owner participants...i directly wanted to get this all the owner field...

Answer (score 0):

So your transaction name needs to match the param section ('addAsset' uppercase) in your transaction logic:

Also would suggest to pass owner as relationship to transaction

In your model

```
transaction addAsset {
o String evidenceId
--> Owner owner
}
```

In your transaction code (something like):

```
/**
* @param {com.acn.hps.aops.ims.addasset} addAsset
* @transaction
*/
function AddingEvidence(addAsset){

console.log('participant is ' + addAsset.owner.AuthorityID);
console.log('getCurrentparticipant is ' + getCurrentParticipant());

// Get the factory for creating new asset instances.
var factory = getFactory();
// Create the Evidence.
var evidence = factory.newResource('com.acn.hps.aops.ims', 'EvidenceDoc', addAsset.evidenceId);

  evidence.owner.ID = addAsset.owner.AuthorityID;

  return getAssetRegistry('com.acn.hps.aops.ims.EvidenceDoc')
     .then(function (registry) {
         return registry.add(evidence );
     });


}
```